# Чтение файла в потоке. Не понятно что жрет память

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Доброе время суток.
Есть программа, которая генерирует лог в диапазоне от 1 до 10 секунд (каждые).
Моя программа читает лог каждые 10сек.
Чтоб не было ошибки:

> Cannot open file …. процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.

Решил вынести чтение лога в отдельный поток.

```
TFileReadThread = class(TThread)
private
{ Private declarations }
PathFile: string;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
public
constructor Create(APathFile: String);      
end;

var
  FileReadThread: TFileReadThread;

constructor TFileReadThread.Create(APathFile: String);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  PathFile := APathFile;
end;

procedure TFileReadThread.Execute;
var
  LFile: TStringList;
  LIndex, LIndex1, LNumGPU, L_Length: integer;
  LValue, LStringParams: string;
  LValueTrue: boolean;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    try
  FMain.lValueStatus.Caption := 'File begin reading';
  FMain.lValueStatus.Font.Color := clGreen;
  LFile := TStringList.Create;
  LFile.LoadFromFile(PathFile);                              
  L_Length := LFile.Count-1;
  LStringParams := '';
  LValueTrue := false;
  LValue := '';
  LNumGPU := 0;


  for LIndex := L_Length downto 0 do
    if Pos('ETH: GPU0', LFile.Strings[LIndex]) <> 0 then
    begin
      FMain.edGPU0.Clear;
      FMain.edGPU1.Clear;
      LStringParams := LFile.Strings[LIndex];
      for LIndex1 := 0 to length(LStringParams) do
      begin
        if (LStringParams[LIndex1] in ['0'..'9']) then
          LValue := LValue+LStringParams[LIndex1]
        else
          if ((LStringParams[LIndex1] = '.')
            or (LStringParams[LIndex1] = ','))
            and (LValue <> '') then
          begin
            LValue := LValue+'.';
            LValueTrue := true;
          end
          else 
          begin
            if (LStringParams[LIndex1] = ' ')
              and (LValueTrue) then
            begin
              if (FMain.edGPU0.Text = '')
                and (LNumGPU = 0) then
                FMain.edGPU0.Text := LValue;
              if (FMain.edGPU1.Text = '')
                and (LNumGPU = 1)  then
                FMain.edGPU1.Text := LValue;  
              inc(LNumGPU);  
            end  
            else LValueTrue := false;
            LValue := '';  
          end;
      end;  
      break;
    end;

  LValue := '';
  LNumGPU := 0;
  for LIndex := L_Length downto 0 do
    if Pos('GPU0 t=', LFile.Strings[LIndex]) <> 0 then
    begin
      FMain.edTemp0.Clear;
      FMain.edTemp1.Clear;
      LStringParams := LFile.Strings[LIndex];
      for LIndex1 := 0 to length(LStringParams) do
      begin
        if (LStringParams[LIndex1] in ['0'..'9']) then
          LValue := LValue+LStringParams[LIndex1]
        else
          begin
            if (LStringParams[LIndex1] = 'C') then
            begin
              if (FMain.edTemp0.Text = '')
                and (LNumGPU = 0) then
                FMain.edTemp0.Text := LValue;
              if (FMain.edTemp1.Text = '')
                and (LNumGPU = 1)  then
                FMain.edTemp1.Text := LValue;  
              inc(LNumGPU);  
            end  
            else LValueTrue := false;
            LValue := '';  
          end;
      end;  
      break;
    end;
     FMain.lValueStatus.Caption := 'File end reading';
     FreeAndNil(LFile);

     FileReadThread.Terminate;
     FileReadThread.WaitFor;
     FreeAndNil(FileReadThread);
except
on E: Exception do
  begin
    FMain.lValueStatus.Caption := 'Not access to file';
    FMain.lValueStatus.Font.Color := clRed;
    LFile.Free;
  end
end;
  end;  
end;
```

Вызываю поток каждые 10сек. С помощью «*Timer*»

```
procedure TFMain.tPollDirectoryTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  LNewFile: TSearchRec;
  LFileTime, LFileSize: integer;
  LPathFile, LFileName: string;
begin
  lValueStatus.Font.Color := clGreen;  
  LFileTime := 0;
  if FindFirst(edPathLog.Text+'*_log.txt', faAnyFile - faDirectory - faVolumeID, LNewFile) = 0 then
  repeat
    if LFileTime = 0 then
    begin
      LFileTime := LNewFile.Time;
      LFileSize := LNewFile.Size;
      LFileName := LNewFile.Name;
    end;

    if LFileTime < LNewFile.Time then
    begin
      LFileTime := LNewFile.Time;
      LFileSize := LNewFile.Size; 
      LFileName := LNewFile.Name; 
    end;  
  until FindNext(LNewFile) <> 0;
  FindClose(LNewFile);

  FileReadThread := TFileReadThread.Create(edPathLog.Text+LFileName);
  FileReadThread.Priority := tpNormal;


  laFileName.Caption := LFileName; 
  laFileTime.Caption := DateTimeToStr(FileDateToDateTime(LFileTime));
  laFileSize.Caption := IntToStr(LFileSize);

  if Pr_OldTime <> 0 then
  begin  
    if (Pr_OldTime = LFileTime) 
      and (Pr_OldSize = LFileSize) then
    begin
      EndPointVolume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(1, nil);    
      SOURCE_BEEP(LOG);

      WRITE_LOG_FILE;
    end;
  end;
  Pr_OldName := LFileName;
  Pr_OldSize := LFileSize;
  Pr_OldTime := LFileTime;
end;
```

В результате я создаю только поток («*FileReadThread*») и «*LFile*», но я их все уничтожаю.

При каждом запуске таймера/потока, у меня идет увеличение памяти.

Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Ошибок куча:

1. Обращение к VCL объектам формы не из главного потока. Такое делать нельзя **никогда**. Обращение из другого потока только через посылку сообщения или через `Synchronize()`
2. `FileReadThread.Terminate;` - обращение к методу/свойству объекта из своего же класса через объектную переменную. Достаточно просто вызвать `Terminate;`
3. `FileReadThread.WaitFor;` ожидание завершения потока в самом потоке. Вы не дождетесь никогда
4. `FreeAndNil(FileReadThread);` попытка разрушить самого себя. Если бы не предыдущий блокирующий `WaitFor` тут бы отгребли кучу AV
5. > Вызываю поток каждые 10сек. С помощью «Timer»

   Почему бы просто не создать один поток и заставлять его пробуждаться через каждые 10 секунд?

Но все это меркнет по сравнению с главным тезисом

> Чтоб не было ошибки:
>
> > «Cannot open file …. процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.»
>
> Решил вынести чтение лога в отдельный поток.

Как отдельный поток сможет избавить Вас от ошибки обращения к файлу, заблокированным другим процессом?

Все, что Вам нужно, это заменить строку

```
LFile.LoadFromFile(PathFile);
```

на

```
LStrm := TFileStream.Create(PathFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
try
  LFile.LoadFromStream(LStrm);
finally
  LStrm.Free;
end;
```

И никаких дополнительных потоков. Но будьте готовы нарваться на файл, который еще не дописан

или даже так

```
repeat
  try
    LStrm := TFileStream.Create(PathFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  except
    on E: EOSError do begin
      if E.ErrorCode = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED then begin
        LStrm := nil;
        Sleep(1000);
      end else
        raise;
    end;
  end;
until LStrm <> nil;
try
  LFile.LoadFromStream(LStrm);
finally
  LStrm.Free;
end;
```

так Вы не нарветесь на недозаписанный файл

---

А вообще все манипуляции с созданием/удалением объектов должны происходить по схеме

```
MyObj := TMyObj.Create;
try
  ........
finally
  MyObj.Free;
end;
```

Чтобы исключения, возникающие после создания объекта не отменяли его уничтожение

Answer (score 1):

Ваш поток рубит сук, на котором сидит:

```
FreeAndNil(FileReadThread);
```

Не используйте глобальную переменную, а используйте `FreeOnTerminate`.

Comment: Он предварительно вешается на этом суку `FileReadThread.WaitFor;`

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, спасибо за ответы, да вот про "synchronize" я забыл... - Я имел ввиду не ошибки, а сист. сообщения о блокировке файла. - Для завершения потока оставилл только "Terminate"...
А все же память (используемая программой) продолжает расти, потихоньку конечно.

Comment: @Konstantin78 Уберите глобальную переменную указывающую на поток. Когда Вы обращаетесь к ней *из потока*, она - с большой вероятностью - не соответствует потоку, который к ней обращается.

Comment: @Konstantin78 `FreeOnTerminate := True`.

Comment: @Konstantin78 FastMM Вам в помощь